# How to send receipts when using new Stripe Checkout beta

Tags: stripe-payments

I integrated "new Stripe Checkout beta" (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) into my project and the only issue I have is that I don't know how to send **Stripe receipts** emails to my customers after a successful payment. Setting "email receipts" on this page https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails don't trigger emails on successful payments.

Currently, the only way I can send receipts is by going into dashboard, finding correct invoice and clicking the "send receipt" button.

Do I have to manually trigger dispatching email receipts via API on successful checkout webhook (checkout_beta.session_succeeded)?

Comment: Is this in test mode or with live charges? I ask because Stripe only sends receipts in live mode. https://support.stripe.com/questions/why-am-i-not-receiving-confirmation-receipt-notification-emails-from-stripe

Comment: Oh, ok. I did not yet pushed my app to production. I was just using Stripe in test mode for now. If that's the case I hope it will automatically work on live :) Thank you @duck !!!